# How can I retrieve all the KeyValuePairs contained in a Dictonary<?,?>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I've got an object which is a Dictionary of an unknown type (ie I don't know the type for the key and the value)

I want to retrieve all of its values so I can access those by index.

So what I want to do is something like that :

```
Dictionary<object, object> d = (Dictionary<object, object>)obj; // cast error
l = new List<KeyValuePair<object,object>>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> k in d)
   l.Add(new KeyValuePair<object,object>(k.Key, k.Value));
```

However, as expected, the runtime won't let me cast to a  Dictionary< object, object>.

Is there a way to do this in .net 3.0 ? (for example using reflection?)

Comment: Hey Brann, tell us a little more about the object? What type is it exactly? What methods and properties does it have?

Comment: Are you certain that the object you're trying to cast as a Dictionary<,> is truly a Dictionary object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cast `obj` to a `Dictionary<object, object>` because it isn't a `Dictionary<object, object>`.  Yes, its keys and values derive from `object`, and can be thus cast to `object`.  But you can't cast generic types in C# because they aren't covariant.  Even though `T` derives from `object`, `List<T>` doesn't derive from `List<object>`.

Consider this method:

```
void ModifyList<List<object> list)
{
   for (int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
   {
      list[i] = list[i].ToString();
   }
}
```

If you could cast `List<int>` to `List<object>`, you could pass a `List<int>` to that method and it would turn into something else.

This is going to change when covariant generics are introduced in C# 4.0.  [This article](http://reddevnews.com/Articles/2009/05/01/Generic-Covariance-and-Contravariance-in-C-40.aspx?Page=1) is a pretty good explanation of the issues involved.

But to solve your actual problem, this will do the trick:

```
List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> list = d.AsEnumerable()
   .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<object, object>(x.Key, x.Value))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: For info; C# 4.0 covariance will make no difference to `List<T>` (nor `IList<T>`, nor any of the dictionary types); only simpler things like `IEnumerable<T>` and the `Func<...>` types; http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-c-40-covariance-doesn-do.html

Comment: Right.  Adding this feature to the language doesn't make casting collection classes a good idea, or even possible.  List<T> is both covariant and contravariant; T is used in both an output position (e.g. the indexer returns an object of type T) and an input position (e.g. Add(T item)).

Answer (score 15):

Since `Dictionary<,>` implements `IDictionary` (non-generic), just iterate that:

```
    IDictionary data = ...
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(de.Key + ": " + de.Value);
    }
```

Comment: I believe the issue is actually with casting an object to a Dictionary<,> as opposed to iterating its entries.

Comment: +1: IDictionary (non-generic) was exactly what I needed to recurse unknown collection objects. Also used non-generic IList for lists, works a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

perhaps:

`foreach (object key in d.keys)
{
 l.Add(new KeyValuePair(key, d[key]);
}`